# Uncaught TypeError: this.set is not a function in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

[this is what error i am getting when i try to edit the array value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm6zs.png)

i want to change an array value on particular index but when i try to do that this i error is being show in console can anyone help me with this.

```js
<script>
//import Vue from 'vue'
import Task from "./Task.vue";
import TaskName from "./TaskName.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Task,
    TaskName,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      Task: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sectionTask(Task) {
      const newTaskTitle = {
        Task: Task,
      };
      this.Task.push(newTaskTitle);
    },
    onremoveTask(Index){
        this.Task.splice(Index, 1)
    },
    onUpdateTaskTitle(Index,newTaskTitle){
      console.log(Index);
      console.log(newTaskTitle);
      this.$set(this.Task, Index, newTaskTitle);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <TaskName @section-task="sectionTask" />
  <Task :Task="Task" @remove="onremoveTask" @update="onUpdateTaskTitle"/>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error using "map" function which is there in Vue.js. Below I am updating the code you can check it out.

Here's what's happening: when you try to update the array that will be referenced somewhere so Vue won't be directly able to update it so first make a copy array and that make changes with it and you can update the array using the map function. Hope you got your answer!

```js
<script>
//import Vue from 'vue'
import Task from "./Task.vue";
import TaskName from "./TaskName.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Task,
    TaskName,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      Task: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sectionTask(Task) {
      const newTaskTitle = {
        Task: Task,
      };
      this.Task.push(newTaskTitle);
    },
    onremoveTask(Index){
        this.Task.splice(Index, 1)
    },
    onUpdateTaskTitle(Index,newTaskTitle){
      console.log(Index);
      console.log(newTaskTitle);
      console.log(this.Task);
      const TaskCopy = this.Task.map(function(element, index) {
         if(index === Index){
           element.Task = newTaskTitle
         }
        return TaskCopy;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <TaskName @section-task="sectionTask" />
  <Task :Task="Task" @remove="onremoveTask" @update="onUpdateTaskTitle"/>
</template>
```

Answer (score 5):

In Vue 3, `this.$set` was removed. See [breaking changes docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/#removed-apis).

[`[].splice` can take values to add new values to the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). So, for your example, you can replace `this.$set` with this:

```js
this.Task.splice(Index, 1, newTaskTitle);
```

This will replace 1 value, starting at `Index`, with `newTaskTitle`.

Comment: So do you know how can change the value of an array at particular index like suppose in array there are three value "A={Task:'A',Task:'B',Task:'C'}" in vue what can i use to change the value of Task:'B' and i want to change it to "Z"

Comment: In Vue 3 simply this.array[index] = value should work. You can test out Vue 3 with sfc.vuejs.org. If you're using Vue 3, you might want to use the setup API, though.

Comment: Hey , i solved it using map function and it worked it gives an array element and its index and you can compare it with your index and change the element easily.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a way to use [].splice, since I guess direct assignment wasn't working for you.